# Given $n$ different points in a plane.

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Given $n$ different points in a plane, $8$ of them are on one straight
> line. The other points are in general everywhere else, so there are no
> $3$ points on same one straight line. How many different triangles can
> you create from these n points?

**What I think is:** *since no three points in the plane are collinear, a triangle can be formed by selecting any three of the $n$ points. The three points can be selected in $^nC_3$ ways, similarly, the number of triangles formed by $8$ collinear points when no three points are collinear in the plane is $^8C_3$. However, the triangles formed by these points are not allowed, so the total number of triangles formed would be ${^nC_3}- {^8C_3}$*

Is that correct?

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Comment: It's correct solution.

Comment: Points in a plane may be collinear.  Did you mean to say that the three vertices of the triangle cannot be collinear?

Comment: isn't that obvious

Answer (score 4):

As has been stated in the comments, your solution is correct; $\binom n3-\binom 83$ different non-degenerate triangles can be formed from this points.